# How do i get rid off extra space on my webpage?

Tags: html, css, layout

I struggle to get rid of extra space on my webpage.
If i am inspecting with chrome dev tools. i don't see: padding, margin or border.

i tryed:

setting margin, padding to 0 on html and body tag

setting height and width of the body and html to 100%

[image: img]

https://ibb.co/SKtTBSn

Comment: Need more information; what space are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

well that happend for me , but at that time i was using a righ to left page (asian lang), i managed to solve it by  going through bootstrap.css and deleting 'text-align:left;' from body class , if it work for you let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule is that you should always make sure your markup is valid (using the W3C validator 234) before you attempt any other form of trouble-shooting – including looking for presentational problems. With invalid markup anything can happen.

Normally, setting `margin:0` and `padding:0` for the `html` and `body` elements, like you have done, should be enough to remove all spacing around the page. But the erroneous markup tags inside the style sheet may throw the parser off.